# AbsSpinner$SavedState cannot be cast to AbsListView$SavedState

Tags: android, orientation, fragment

my problem, I believe, is that I have a gallery in portrait mode and a listview in landscape mode.  They're both using the same adapter and in the same view.  However, on orientation change, the listview attempts to read the information from the gallery and the program crashes.

The gallery reads the list's information fine when it restores.  It is the list that cannot read the gallery's save state.  I've attached the stack trace below though it tells me very little.  Any light that you could shed would be helpful!  Target api is 3.0 btw.

```
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.awesome.OASAC/com.awesome.OASAC.OASACActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsSpinner$SavedState cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3096)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:997)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsSpinner$SavedState cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onRestoreInstanceState(AbsListView.java:1520)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:8101)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchThawSelfOnly(ViewGroup.java:1972)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(AdapterView.java:766)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1958)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:8080)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:516)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:742)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:921)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:904)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1579)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4320)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1709)
07-22 20:58:35.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2191):     ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, you have both the `Gallery` and the `ListView` named the same. You cannot safely do that, as you have discovered. Change one of their names to something distinct. You will also need to override `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` to convert between the two instance states yourself (in addition to chaining to the superclass from each of those methods to inherit the default behavior).